# SQLDeveloper creates "truncated" schema dump

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 Oracle databases v 11.2.0.4.0 (Prod and Test) with the same schema.

Using Oracle SQLDeveloper v.20.2.0.175, 'Tools -> Database Export ...' (Add Force to Views, Grants, Pretty Print, Show Schema, Terminator), no data export, 'Proceed to summary' checked.

The operation gets completed successfully in both cases.

But one database export is a kind of truncated: if I compare diffs, I obviously see that one database export is stopped at views DDLs, while the other ("healthy") export file additionally includes: Synonyms, top-level Functions, Procedures, Packages, Constraints and Indexes.

What can be the reason one database export is incomplete? Several months ago I did same dumps and output files were complete for both databases.

**UPD**: While making many attempts, I noticed there is always a reconnect
[image: disconnect]

happening approximately after

```sql
select i.index_name from all_indexes ...
```

Statements logging tab shows this query takes tens of seconds on 'Elapsed' column. If I execute this query manually, it takes 2-3 seconds. I think this is directly related to truncated output.

Comment: are you logging in as the schema for the sql developer connection? are you checking everything on the 2nd page of the wizard? you say you go to 'proceed to summary' - it's possible that only tables and views are checked for your exports?

Comment: if you had dba level privs, we could hit DBA_INDEXES instead - the dba views are much faster

Comment: @thatjeffsmith this definitely was not caused by access rights or missing checkboxes. Just used another machine with the same credentials and the process completed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by reconnect happening all the time at a query looking for indexes. I just used SQL Developer on another Windows machine and the export was successful and complete.